# how to change the action of a form when the submit button is pressed || make the submit button clickable only once?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there was a way to make a submit button in html on clickable once, I am having an issue with users submitting multiple lines of information into a database because of impatience. I know this is the issue because I have tested it myself, the php written for the queries is solid, the problem is I have users that are impatient.

So my question is this, is there any code regardless of the language be it javascript, jquery, php or otherwise that I can use to either change the action of the form so that it can't be resubmitted over and over again, or to change the type of button of the submit button. I know that I can use javascript to change an element and its contents but is that really necessary or is there a simpler way?

thanks for all of your help.

Comment: show your code what you tried?

Comment: This is far too broad. However, you can use sessions with a token which will help prevent this. JS alone can only go so far.

Comment: ...this is what I'm talking about http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Preventing-Multiple-Submits.html

Comment: In my opinion, if you have something on the server side that takes a long time, it is much less frustrating to your users if you do something on the client side to indicate that their request has been received and is actually being processed, but is just taking a while, rather than disabling the button. Obviously they are impatient, most people are, but they are probably only clicking the button repeatedly because they think nothing is happening. Why they think clicking again will make something happen is beyond me, but people certainly do it.

Comment: `Don't Panic` has made a good point +1. You could look into what I've mentioned above, including an Ajax method to show them a message that something is going on, and to wait till the (animated icon) disappears.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I also agree there, although I disagree that disabling the button isn't better than nothing -- it removes the "wait, did I actually click that button" doubt, leaving only the "I wonder if it's broken and not working" doubt.

Comment: @zebediah49 Good point, that is true! But I do think if we're already including a script to change the interface as an indication to the user, it isn't much more trouble to also give them a reassuring message.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabaling the button once clicked ? You Could Try something like this.

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
$("#TargitFormId").submit();
alert("Please wait while we save your information");
//Or you could use a nicer UI Here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use .submit() instead of .click. Beacuse user may use enter key for submit form. So you can use this code

```
var hadSent=false;
$("#FormId").submit(function(event){
if(hadSent==true){event.preventDefault()}
hadSent=true; // for prevent next submitions
})
```